# I'm trying to pull the table values on a website, but an empty list appears

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract data from this site using python, but when I pull the beautifulsoup and request libraries the data in this table, an empty list is created. Can you help me with this?

[table in the URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAltG.png)

[the website](https://www.mackolik.com/mac/trabzonspor-vs-sivasspor/karsilastirma/5x6r419402ucyya2zf0ehbqxg)

```
url2 = "https://www.mackolik.com/mac/trabzonspor-vs-sivasspor/karsilastirma/5x6r419402ucyya2zf0ehbqxg"
r= requests.get(url2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
table = soup.find_all('ul',class_ = "Opta-TabbedContent")
table
out: []
```

Comment: Does the site use javascript to dynamically create page content?  `requests` doesn't do javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is dynamically loaded and hence python requests cannot get the data. You need a headless browser such as selenium:

```
 from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

 url = "https://www.mackolik.com/mac/trabzonspor-vs-sivasspor/karsilastirma/5x6r419402ucyya2zf0ehbqxg"
 options = Options()
 options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Comment: The problem was solved this way. Thank you so much.